# Spring Boot in STS isn't using generated code classes

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am trying to use mapstruct generated classes on a new spring-boot project(personal), and it seems my build script requires something else.

The classes are being generated correctly cause I can see them(java and class files in the build folder) and when the application is executed from the jar file, it actually works.

The problem is that when it is executed from eclipse STS, it says spring cant find the generated clases, and yes I made sure, they are created using @Component, and are in the ComponentScanPath.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

ext {
    javaLanguageLevel = '1.8'
    generatedMapperSourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-src/mapstruct/main"
}
configurations {
    mapstruct
}
sourceSets.main {
    ext.originalJavaSrcDirs = java.srcDirs
    java.srcDir "${generatedMapperSourcesDir}"
}
jar {
    baseName = 'MtgGrimoire'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws")
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41')
    compile( 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.0.0.Beta1' )
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    mapstruct( 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.0.0.Beta1' )
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

task generateMainMapperClasses(type: JavaCompile) {
    ext.aptDumpDir = file( "${buildDir}/tmp/apt/mapstruct" )
    destinationDir = aptDumpDir

    classpath = compileJava.classpath + configurations.mapstruct
    source = sourceSets.main.originalJavaSrcDirs
    ext.sourceDestDir = file ( "$generatedMapperSourcesDir" )

    options.define(
        compilerArgs: [
            "-nowarn",
            "-proc:only",
            "-encoding", "UTF-8",
            "-processor", "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
            "-s", sourceDestDir.absolutePath,
            "-source", rootProject.javaLanguageLevel,
            "-target", rootProject.javaLanguageLevel,
        ]
    );

    inputs.dir source
    outputs.dir generatedMapperSourcesDir;
    doFirst {
         sourceDestDir.mkdirs()
    }
    doLast {
        aptDumpDir.delete()
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn generateMainMapperClasses
```

Also it seems it isn't generated inside the project bin folder

Comment: I doubt the Eclipse support in Gradle (or vice versa) knows about your "${buildDir}/generated-src/mapstruct/main" sources. Maybe you can just add that as a src folder in the Eclipse IDE manually?

Comment: yeah, thats what I think, to, but was looking for a way to use it without couping, as they will end up changing alot

Comment: for now, I made the sources to be generated inside de original src folder, but I would like to know if there is a better solution